# Regularity for "general form" Monge-Ampère equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

I'm looking for conditions under which the following general form Monge-Ampère equation has a $\mathcal{C}^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$-solution:

$$ det(D^2u-A(x,u))=B(x,u).$$

I'm not sure whether such conditions exist at all as I'm looking for a solution on an **unbounded** domain (which matters, right?).

The three cases I'm interested in are

1. $B=0$
2. $B\geq0$
3. $B\geq c>0$.

For this equation I could only find results on a bounded domain. Furthermore, to my maybe flawed understanding the Evans-Krylov can only apply in case 3. Also some results only apply to the case where $B=B(x,\nabla u)$...

Any reference is welcome, too!

Thanks in advance and sorry for my lack of PDE-knowledge...

Comment: Do you care about the existence or are you happen to consider the question “given a (suitably weak) solution, is it $C^2$?” I ask because existence theory is in unbounded domains is usually very different than in bounded domains, but the (interior) regularity theory is the same

Comment: Also, are you assuming $u$ is convex? I believe this is important for the regularity theory of the Monge-Ampere equation

Comment: Yes, mainly care about existence and am looking for a convex solution. There has been recent work on this equation by Trudinger et al. but it's mostly on bounded domains, from what I understand...